# Group by with having and merge back to original table

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle10g

I have a table like this

| A_Count | B_Count | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | A | NULL | C1 |
| 0 | 1 | NULL | B | C1 |
| 1 | 1 | A | B | C2 |
| 1 | 1 | A | B | C2 |

and I want to have a result table (only need to show column A and B) like:

| A_Count | B_Count | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | B | C1 |
| 1 | 1 | A | B | C2 |
| 1 | 1 | A | B | C2 |

So my goal is to merge two row having the following condiction:
both rows belong to same group C and only merge when one row has A being null and one row has B being null.

so its like:
group by C
having sum(A_COUNT) =1 AND sum(B_COUNT) =1

but the problem is, I want to keep those rows that are not merged (ROW 3 & 4) , can someone tell me how to do that? many thanks!

Comment: How many pairs of rows do you need to merge for each `C` value? Will there only ever be one pair or could there be multiple pairs?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Oracle 12 then you could use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT a_count, b_count, a, b, c
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         NVL2(
           A,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C ORDER BY NVL2( B, 1, 0 ) DESC, ROWNUM ),
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C ORDER BY NVL2( A, 1, 0 ) DESC, ROWNUM )
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY C
  ORDER     BY rn, A NULLS LAST
  MEASURES
    FIRST( a_count ) AS a_count,
    LAST( b_count )  AS b_count,
    FIRST( a )       AS a,
    LAST( b )        AS b
  PATTERN ( a b? )
  DEFINE
    a AS a.a IS NOT NULL,
    b AS a.b IS NULL AND b.a IS NULL AND b.b IS NOT NULL
)
```

Before that Oracle version, you can get a similar effect using analytic functions to determine which rows to aggregate:

```sql
SELECT SUM( a_count ) AS a_count,
       SUM( b_count ) AS b_count,
       MAX( a ) AS a,
       MAX( b ) AS b,
       c
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         NVL2(
           A,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C ORDER BY NVL2( B, 1, 0 ) DESC, ROWNUM ),
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY C ORDER BY NVL2( A, 1, 0 ) DESC, ROWNUM )
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY c, rn
```

Which, for the sample data (in an unordered state, with additional rows to demonstrate grouping additional pairs of rows):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( A_Count, B_Count, A, B, C ) AS
SELECT 1, 0, 'A',  NULL, 'C1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 1, NULL, 'B',  'C1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'A',  'B',  'C2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 1, NULL, 'B',  'C2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Added row
SELECT 1, 0, 'A',  NULL, 'C2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Added row
SELECT 1, 0, 'A',  NULL, 'C2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Added row
SELECT 1, 1, 'A',  'B',  'C2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0, 1, NULL, 'B',  'C2' FROM DUAL           -- Added row
```

Both output:

> ```
> A_COUNT | B_COUNT | A  | B  | C 
> ------: | ------: | :- | :- | :-
>       1 |       1 | A  | B  | C1
>       1 |       1 | A  | B  | C2
>       1 |       1 | A  | B  | C2
>       1 |       1 | A  | B  | C2
>       1 |       1 | A  | B  | C2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dfe184060952bca1d8ba8a52c7520fab)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional `analytical function` and `group by` as follows:

```
Select max(a) as a, max(b) as b, c from 
  (Select a, b, c, 
          case when nulla = 1 and nullb = 1 and (a is null or b is null)
               then 0
               else row_number() over (partition by c order by 1)
          end as rn 
     from (Select a, b, c, 
                  count(case when a is null then 1 end) over(partition by c) as nulla, 
                  count(case when b is null then 1 end) over (partition by c) as nullb
             From your_table t
           )
  )
Group by c, rn
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aaa01ae58d52ed4149344f926c21ef63) Thanks to MT0. Used the sample data from MT0's fiddle.

Comment: If you add a pair of rows similar to the pair for `C1` to the `C2` set of rows then your query will aggregate all the `C2` rows into one row [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fafc6785c79ffc2571ce6c59df5abedd).

Comment: @MT0 Yes, you are right. I have updated my answer and db<>fiddle also to handle this condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `join`:

```
select (t1.a_count + coalesce(t2.a_count, 0)) as a_count,
       (t1.b_count + coalesce(t2.b_count, 0)) as b_count,
       coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) as a,
       coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b,
       t1.c
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.c = t2.c and
        t1.a is not null and t2.a is null and
        t1.b is null and t2.b is not null
where t1.a is not null;
```

As you've described the problem, aggregation doesn't seem necessary.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0e14d7758e5268ba9b8a640348e01c58) is a db<>fiddle with your original data.